# How to assign the domain name to the port in Docker

Tags: laravel, docker

I mounted Laravel on port 80 in Docker and this is my service in docker-compose.yml

```
  webserver:
    image: nginx:alpine
    container_name: webserver
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
    - "8000:80"
    - "8443:443"
    volumes:
    - ./:/var/www/docker/example/api
    - ./nginx/conf.d/:/etc/nginx/conf.d/
```

I want to mapping 8000 port from ubuntu with 80 on docker that you see is done.
and the site comes up with this address http://ip_server:8000

I want to come up with the domain name of the site without entering the port

```
server {
    listen 80;
    index index.php index.html;
    server_name example.com;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    root /var/www/docker/khesarat/api/public;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass app:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case and what I have done in my case is to run another `nginx` container listening on port `80`. Add `nginx` and `webserver` containers to the same network, then you should see what you want.

Do as below:

- Run `docker network create NAME`
- Run `docker run -dp80:80 --network NAME -v /path/domain.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/ nginx:alpine
- Create a `domain.conf` file like this:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name DOMAIN;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

        proxy_pass http://webserver:8000; # you also can remove :8000
        proxy_redirect off;

        # Socket.IO Support
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    }
}
```

- Change your current `docker-compose.yml` to:

```
webserver:
    image: nginx:alpine
    container_name: webserver
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
    - "8000:80"
    - "8443:443"
    volumes:
    - ./:/var/www/docker/example/api
    - ./nginx/conf.d/:/etc/nginx/conf.d/
networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: NAME
```

In this case you also can remove `ports` mapping directive from your `docker-compose` file since it's not needed.

Answer (score 0):

If I am not confused, you would have to map it to `80`, and then edit your `host` file (depends on what OS you are in) and add `127.0.0.1 example.com` and it will automatically resolve to it.